# Organizing an iOS App with Storyboards

Tags: xcode, organization

I'm new to iOS programming and being the organizational freak that I am, I'd like to have a good clean structure for everything I am working on.

1. Should I create real folders to represent the groups that I have created in Xcode and organize my code that way?
2. Should I rename the groups I have now to any other names?
3. I am going to be needing an API, where should I put it?

Here's my current layout:

[image]

This project is open source: https://github.com/kirkouimet/enzyme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really up to you. It's sort of subjective, but usually Xcode's project templates provide a good start. Generally, I prefer Groups over literal folder references with the exception of the first couple of root-level directories.

Here's the typical file-system structure for my projects:

[image]

And here's what my Xcode project structure typically looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is a great storyboard tutorial series. not sure if it will answer all your organizational questions, but still a good place to start:

[storyboarding tutorial series](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)